# how to define two parameter in laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.3

im using laravel 5.4 and i have a brands and a products table. i want to define two parameter in route and get them in controller or RouteServiceProvider to search.

imagine : site.com/samsung/   =>  get all products with samsung brand.

and     : site.com/samsung/galaxys8  =>  get all products with samsung brand and galaxys8 model

i can define this using two separate route and controller method : (define route one with 1 parameter{brand} and controller@method1 and define route two with 2 parameters {brand}/{product} and controller@method2)

can i do this better? im a little new in laravel . thank you

```
Route::get('/{brand}', 'AdvertismentController@show');
Route::get('/{brand}/{product}', 'AdvertismentController@show2');



public function show($brand)
{
        $brands = Advertisment::where('brand' , $brand)->get();
        return $brands;
}

public function show2($brand , $product)
{
    $products = Advertisment::where('product' , $product)->get();
    return $products;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess that you want to combine the similar controller actions, you can use optional parameters like this:

```
Route::get('/{brand}/{product?}', 'AdvertismentController@show');

public function show($brand, $product = null)
{
    if (!is_null($product)) {
        $results = Advertisment::where('product' , $product)->get();
    } else {
        $results = Advertisment::where('brand' , $brand)->get();
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: veery nice . it worked. but can you explain me what is that question mark after product in routes? thank you

Comment: The question mark after parameter name make the presence of parameter optional.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: how can we pass multiple optional parameters and use them?

Answer (score 6):

Just like on this example question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681715/passing-multiple-parameters-to-controller-in-laravel-5)

You pass two arguments on the URI:

```
Route::get('/{brand}/{product}', 'AdvertismentController@show2');
```

And on the view:

```
route('remindHelper',['brand'=>$brandName, 'product'=>productId]);
```

Comment: And what in controller? To get them

Comment: In the controller you can have something like:
public function show($brand, $product)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($product);
 
    return view('product.show', compact('brand', 'product'));
}

Comment: how can we pass multiple optional parameters and use them?