# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers 0 passed and exactly 2 expected"

Tags: php, laravel

I know there are solutions but none of them working for me.
Here is my hyperlink

```
<a href="{{route('voting',$parameters = array('id' =>$answers->id,'votes' =>"1"))}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a>
```

This is my route
First i tried this one

```
 Route::get('voting','AnswerController@voting')->name("voting");
```

then this one

```
Route::get('voting',array('as'=>'voting','uses'=>'AnswerController@voting'));
```

My Controller

```
public function voting($id,$votes){
        //rest  of code 
}
```

problem i am facing

> "Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\AnswerController::voting(), 0 passed and exactly
>   2 expected"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to give the route 2 parameters

```
Route::get('voting/{id}/{votes}', array('as'=>'voting','uses'=>'AnswerController@voting'));
```

Refer to this thread

[Passing multiple parameters to controller in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681715/passing-multiple-parameters-to-controller-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<a href="{{ route('voting',['id' => $answers->id, 'votes' => 1]) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a>
```

Instead of

```
<a href="{{route('voting',$parameters = array('id' =>$answers->id,'votes' =>"1"))}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a>
```