# Laravel 5 - How to pass multiple parameter in GET route?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Can anyone please help me to pass multiple parameters in GET method, I have following codes -

**in blade -**

```
 @if(!isset($model->id_car_type))
     <a class="btn btn-search-red" href="{{ route('frontend.model', [Request::segment(2),$model->year,$model->niceName]) }}">Select</a>
 @else
     <a class="btn btn-search-red" href="{{ route('frontend.model', array(Request::segment(2),$model->year,$model->niceName, $model->id_car_type)) }}">Select</a>
 @endif
```

**In route -**

```
Route::get('/model/{make}/{year}/{niceName}/{type?}', 'GeneralController@trimShowByNiceName')->name('frontend.model');
```

But it is throwing error -

> Missing required parameters for [Route: frontend.model] [URI:
>   model/make/{make}/year/{year}/niceName/{niceName}/{type?}]

Comment: Maybe this will help you.
[Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681715/passing-multiple-parameters-to-controller-in-laravel-5)

Comment: I have tried but couldn't success

Comment: Debugging is the best way to find solution and trust me it works 90% of the times. Let me guide you to the right path, in route (backend) there are certain parameters which are set as required. Log request body of the route and check which one of the required parameters are not being received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass parameters in a route use an array with the paramter names as keys:

```
{{ route('frontend.model', ['make' => 'Ford', 'year' => 1988, 'niceName' => 'Ford Escort']) }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes

Comment: Thank you for your response, and what about route.php? How it should be in that file?

Comment: Your route looks ok to me

Comment: Still it is throwing error - Missing required parameters for [Route: frontend.model] [URI: model/{make}/{year}/{niceName}/{type?}]

Comment: Have you tried this with "dynamic" parameters, coming from your database or so? Maybe one of them is empty/null? Anything in your laravel.log?

Comment: And are you sure you got the correct code? The error message you get mentions `model/make/{make}/year/{year}/niceName/{niceName}/{type?}` which seems to be a different route than the one you posted?!

Comment: When I use -  Route::get('/model/{niceName}/{type?}', 'GeneralController@trimShowByNiceName')->name('frontend.model');
it is working but the url is generating like  http://localhost/devcar/model/acura/2019?mdx

Comment: Smashing my head!! there was another code of piece commented in the blade, don't know why it was causing error if commented - <!-- View Details -->
                                <!--a href="{{ route('frontend.model', $model->id_car_model) }}" class="view-details">Select
                                </a-->

Comment: @if(!isset($model->id_car_type))
     <a class="btn btn-search-red" href="{{ route('frontend.model', ['make' =>Request::segment(2),'year' =>$model->year,'niceName' =>$model->niceName]) }}">Select</a>
 @ your answer should like this

Comment: @MHFuad My answer is fine as is.

Comment: how can we pass multiple optional parameters and use them?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.2 use the following example:

In the view.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('users', [$users->id, $users->name]) }}">Page</a>
```

In the route.php

```
`Route::get('users/{id}{name}', 'UsersController@searchUsers'); // this gets the id, name` from the view url.
```

In the controller method, pass the parameters as function parameters as follows:

```
 public function searchUsers($id, $name)
    {
      // your code here that use the parameters
    }
```