# Laravel pass multiple parameters to named route

Tags: php, html, laravel, named-routing

I've gotten stuck on a passing additional parameters to a named route.
I have found how to do it on [Laravel doc's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes) as well as an answer on [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777156/laravel-5-how-to-pass-multiple-parameter-in-get-route).

My problem is I cannot get to my delete function in the controller, when I click the link the page refreshes and throws no errors but does not get to the controller.

What could be wrong with my route?

Route:

```
Route::delete('/assets/{asset}/{model}', 'AssetManagmentController@destroy')->name('asset.delete');
```

Href:

```
<td data-label="Destroy:"><a href="{{ route('asset.delete', ['asset' => $row->id, 'model' => $key] ) }}" data-method="DELETE" data-destoy='destroy' name="delete_item">Destroy</a></td>

<td data-label="Destroy:"><a href="{{ route('asset.delete', ['asset' => 'id', 'model' => 'model'] ) }}" data-method="DELETE" data-destoy='destroy' name="delete_item">Destroy</a></td>
```

Comment: You are using delete route while you are sending get request either change route to get or your request to delete request

Comment: (Once you get answer(s) below, there is no need to copy that into your question. Self-answers are welcome here, but please make them in an answer post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data-method="DELETE"` will not magically make your link do a `DELETE` request. Anchor tags can only send `GET` requests.

You will either have to create a `GET` route that can be used with an anchor tag, or create a form [that can be spoofed to send a `DELETE` request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#method-field).

Comment: Any suggestions on the correct way of passing an additional parameter to the delete route?

Comment: You are already passing the parameters correctly to your delete route. It's just the request type that is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

i have tested in my system and it's worked.

here my woking code

```
<td>
  <form method="post" id="delete-form-{{ $post->id }}" action="{{ route('post.destroy', $post->id) }}" style="display: none;"> @csrf @method('DELETE') </form>
  <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure, You want to delete this?')) { event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('delete-form-{{ $post->id }}').submit(); }">
    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
  </a>
</td>
```

i hope this is helps you

Comment: Your solution only makes use of one parameter have you tested it with more than one?

Comment: I did make use of your onclick event though thanks for that +1

Answer (score 1):

On based on route you mention in question, need to create form with delete request.

like.

```
<td data-label="Destroy:">
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['asset.delete', $row->id, $key], 'method' => 'delete']) }}
<button type="submit">Destroy</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your information is given,
u Juts need to change in HREF of anchor tag change route to route('asset/assets_id/Modelname').

```
Route::delete('/asset/{id}/{model}','AssetManagmentController@destory')->name('assets.delete');

<td data-label="Destroy:"><a href="{{ route('asset/assets_id/Modelname') }}" data-method="DELETE" data-destoy='destroy' name="delete_item">Destroy</a></td>
```

Comment: That wont work unfortunately, gives error: route not defined